# Can someone facilitate the merging of tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

How about merging the magical objects and magical items tags? It seems redundant to have both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done:-) So far as you see something like this, then let someone know, and we'll try and take care of it.